# Putting constraints on possible combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here's a word problem I want to understand.

**On a recent trip, my niece packed four pair of shorts, six t-shirts, and three pair of footwear.**

**a) How many different outfits can she create if she is required one of each apparel?**

**b) Assume the shorts are blue, black, red, and green.  If she can only wear three of the shirts with the red shorts and two of the shirts with the green shorts, how many different outfits can she create if she is required one of each apparel?**

I know the answer to a is 4 * 6 * 3 by the Multiplication Principle. How do I solve b? What method/principle can I use?

Comment: Use the addition principle in combination with the multiplication principle.  That is to say, count the possibilities where you have red shorts, count the possibilities where you have green shorts, count the possibilities where you have either of the other types of shorts, and add those individual results together.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the problem is that you can't follow a formula blindly.  That is, you have to intuitively understand how a formula was derived, before understanding how to **adjust the computation, on-the-fly**.

Ignore the issue of footwear, and focus only on shorts and t-shirts.

Label the shorts as $S_B, S_L, S_R, S_G$, to represent the blue, black, red, and green shorts, respectively.

Label the t-shirts as $T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4, T_5, T_6.$

Then, suppose that the original question had merely asked for the number of distinct [shorts::t-shirts] combinations, with no restrictions, based on the color of the shorts.  Then, the corresponding enumeration of

$$4 \times 6$$

actually represents:

- $S_B : [T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_6].$
- $S_L : [T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_6].$
- $S_R : [T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_6].$
- $S_G : [T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_6].$

Under the added constraints, the above chart (**intuitively**) changes to

- $S_B : [T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_6].$
- $S_L : [T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_6].$
- $S_R : [T_1, T_2, T_3].$
- $S_G : [T_1, T_2].$

So, under the added constraints, the enumeration changes from

$$6 + 6 + 6 + 6$$

to

$$6 + 6 + 3 + 2 = 17.$$

The wrinkle is that you are then supposed to recognize that for each of the $(17)$ satisfying [shorts::t-shirt] combinations, there are $3$ choices for the footwear.

So, the intended computation is

$$\left[6 + 6 + 3 + 2\right] \times 3.$$